# What's the difference between mockitoSession and MockitoAnnotations.initMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng

I read about mockitoSession and also about MockitoAnnotations.initMocks but i didn't understand what is the difference between the two?

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Mockito.mockitoSession()
            .initMocks(this)
            .strictness(Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
            .startMocking();
```

what does mockitoSession does that MockitoAnnotations doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) method has to called to initialize annotated fields.

MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); initializes fields annotated with Mockito annotations.
Allows shorthand creation of objects required for testing.
Minimizes repetitive mock creation code.
Makes the test class more readable.
Makes the verification error easier to read because field name is used to identify the mock.

Where as

MockitoSession is a session of mocking, during which the user creates and uses Mockito mocks. Typically the session is an execution of a single test method. MockitoSession initializes mocks, validates usage and detects incorrect stubbing. When the session is started it must be concluded with finishMocking() otherwise UnfinishedMockingSessionException is triggered when the next session is created.

MockitoSession is useful when you cannot use MockitoJUnitRunner or MockitoRule. For example, you work with TestNG instead of JUnit. Another example is when different JUnit runner is in use (Jukito, Springockito) and it cannot be combined with Mockito's own runner.

Comment: so the difference is that mockitosession is for single test and initMocks for whole class test? because MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); also initializes mocks, validates usage and detects incorrect stubbing(as far as i noticed for it's errors).   Can you give an example of when to use MockitoAnnotations and when to use MockitoSession ?

Comment: Downvote for blatant copy pasta from the docs without references.